# can anyone explain unexpected state transition with ui-router and back button?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-router with nested states/views and I'm having a problem with the back button.

### State hierarchy

- product

  - personal

    - sub-cat-1
    - sub-cat-2
  - business

    - sub-cat-a
    - sub-cat-b
- search

### Problem

I initially load the page in state `product.business.sub-cat-a`. The top level page has a search input form which, when used, causes a state transition to state `search` (via a call to `$state.go()`) which all works fine.

However, if I click on the back button, I see the state transition from `search` to `product.business.sub-cat-a` as expected (via a call to `$state.transitionTo()`), but then there is an additional call to `$state.go()` back to state `search` and I can't work out where this call is coming from.

Would appreciate some help if anyone can shed some light on what ui-router is doing

### Update

I've traced the problem down to the interaction between the `urlRouter` and `$location`. Seems `$urlRouter.update` sometimes pushes a url defined in a stat to `$location` and sometime pulls the value out of `$location`.

In this case, when things go wrong, the `urlRouter` location value is the old url which overwrites the `$location.url` value and causes the `urlRouter` to load the old state rather than the state we are trying to go back to.

The sequence seems to be:

1. click back button
2. browser loads the previous url from it's history
3. ui-router goes about loading the correct state (the previous state)
4. update is called on `urlRouter` (without read parameter) which causes `$location` to be reset to the pre-back button state url based on the urlRouter location value
5. `urlRouter` then sees the two urls/states as different so it reloads the state now specified by `$location.url` which is the pre-back button url

So the problem seems to be that `urlRouter` location value isn't updated when the state is updated in step 3 above.

Any ui-router/angular experts, please feel free to point me in the right direction.

Comment: updated to angularjs v 1.2.27 but still experiencing the same problem

Comment: seems like $location is being updated incorrectly by ui-router code although it may still be my fault. I'll update when I get to the bottom of it

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who faces a similar problem, the issue here was that when the back button was pressed, two state transitions were triggered. The first was the correct one resulting from the back button; the second was a $state.go() associated with the parent (business) state as shown in the hierarchy above.

The second transition was processed before the promises generated by the `resolve` step had been resolved. This meant that the `urlRouter` location hadn't been updated before the subsequent `$urlRoute.udpate()` call and so the router reloaded the original page.

Hope this may help save someone else a day of debugging :-)

Comment: So what was the solution?

Comment: so long ago now! we did this in a test app and haven't kept the code. Sorry!